# 'Empty' tag excerpt edit automatically submitted when editing just the tag wiki

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, tag-excerpt

I'm currently replacing [some](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6118699#6118699) HTTP links with HTTPS links in tag wikis across the network, as part of the [HTTP to HTTPS migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058/295232).

Usually, I just need to change the tag wiki and not the excerpt. On Stack Overflow **(only)**, when submitting the changes, this leads to an empty excerpt edit: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16479180) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16479143). On other sites I've tried it works fine.

[image]

Comment: *"I'm currently replacing some HTTP links with HTTPS links in tag wikis across the network"* Why wasn't that done automatically, like links in answers? And for whatever reason that it wasn't, why can't it be done that way now?

Comment: Good question – FWIW, I'm not just replacing internal links but external links as well, if possible. Not all of those support HTTPS and they need to be checked manually. (And I'm also checking for grammatical errors.)