# Pending limit for wiki tag edits

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I've recently started making edits to tag wikis.  I navigated to another tag after making a few edits and now when I click edit, I don't see a text-area for editing.  This is all I see:

[image]

Is there a limit for how many pending tag wiki edits you can have open at one time?

If so, I propose we show a small message stating "You've reached the limit for pending tag edits".

Comment: I see *edit pending* on one of the [tag wiki's](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/price/info) you suggested an edit on.

Comment: Oh, and for price that is an awful edit, sorry. The excerpt should explain when to use the tag for a question. People know what price is, they just need guidance if the tag is appropriate on the question.

Comment: Do note that you don't need to put an apostrophe before the s when making something plural. That goes for wikis too, @rene ;)

Comment: I'll put fancy apostrophe's where ever I can @MikeMcCaughan ... ;) .. point taken.

Comment: @rene,  Thanks for the clarification, I'm new to the wiki edits I'll try to be more clear next time

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318337/how-do-i-write-a-good-tag-wiki-is-it-okay-to-use-copy-content-published-elsewhe if you haven't already @johnny5 ...

Comment: See also now https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408422/unclear-failure-mode-for-wiki-edit-attempts-when-you-have-too-many-pending-edits

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is there a limit for how many pending wiki tag edits you can have open at one time?

Yes, it's [five](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281202/295232); suggested edits to tag wiki and tag excerpt are treated the same way as suggested edits to posts.

---

Actually, it's possible to have *six* pending edits, because if you have four of them pending, you can still open a tag wiki edit page and change both the tag wiki and the excerpt. Because you're submitting them together, the system will accept this.

Comment: Thanks,  Hopefully we can just add that status message for this page when we reach the pending limit

Comment: So, in practice, if there is no tag excerpt and no wiki, you'll only be able to submit changes for **3** tags at a time, right? (because system won't let you submit an edit with a missing excerpt/wiki)

Comment: @Cœur it *should* be possible to add just an excerpt and no wiki. I've done that countless times before (mostly on other sites of the network). What you describe looks like [this bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351041/4751173).