# Improve Tag Info button does not indicate you have too many pending edits

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-wiki

I tried to edit a tag wiki to get my Tag Editor badge, but upon clicking the "Improve Tag Info" button I was taken to the tag wiki info page which is identical to simply clicking the "Learn more..." button. I tried to figure out what was going on figuring I had insufficient permissions and eventually just gave up.

I did not realize until now that this was because I already had 5 pending edits, and am now able to edit tag wikis correctly by clicking "Improve Tag Info".

I think that the "Improve Tag Info" button needs to have a red popup box indicating the edit queue is full/you have too many pending edits to avoid confusion.

Comment: I find the whole "Workflow"/Navigation for a Tag rather "cumbersome" anyway...: The `Learn more...` Link should be named `Tag Wiki` (or `Tag Info`), there is no need for a direct Link `Improve tag info` from the Tag Page, (where only the Excerpt is displayed btw...), that Link could be placed at the bottom of the 'Tag Wiki' Page, next to the `History` & `Excerpt history` Links... (My 2cts...)

Comment: Thread related to Qt: "Pending limit for wiki tag edits" ( https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367745/pending-limit-for-wiki-tag-edits )

Comment: @chivracq: 100% agreed.  Very little points people towards the existence of high-quality collections of links like https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c++/info or  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.  "Learn more..." doesn't sound like it's going to be that.

Comment: @Peter, woaw...!, very good Qlt indeed, Thanks for the Links/Examples, even for "myself"... I recently created the Wiki Tag for the small Tag I answer ( https://stackoverflow.com/tags/imacros/info ) and I was looking for that kind of (good Qlt) Examples... Mostly 1-Rep Users in "my" Tag, that I used to refer to my own Profile (but only the first 5 or 6 Lines now visible with the new "Reactive Profile") for "minimum [Quality/Info to include] Requirements", now I have to explain that `Learn more...` is the Link to the Tag Wiki with all Recommendations on how to ask "a good" Qt in the Tag...

Comment: @chivracq: I normally just link the tag wiki directly in answers or comments when I want to mention it, rather than telling people how to navigate to it.

Comment: @Peter, yeah..., but several other "Sub"-Tags often get added to those Qt's, (1-Rep Users always think the more Tags, = the bigger the "Answering Pool", = the more Chance to get an Answer/some Help), and I can't/don't want to link to all the Tag Wikis for all those Tags..., as they also need to "respect" the Tag Usage for those Tags if they added them to their Qt.

Comment: About "that Link could be placed at the bottom of the 'Tag Wiki' Page, next to the `History` & `Excerpt history` Links..." from my 1st Comment, I now have an `Edit tag info` (Blue) Button left of the 2 'History' Links I mentioned on the Tag Wiki Page of all Tags I check..., which I certainly didn't have 13 hours ago... Woaw...!, quick "Response" from Dev...! (But the `Improve tag info` Link is still present on the Tag Page itself..., which I still find useless...: Maybe ONE (Advanced) User in the Tag needs to click on that Link once a year, and they'll find the Button from the Wiki Page...)

Comment: @chivracq: Oh, I was thinking of cases where I specifically want to link https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info because it has relevant links.  Many of the other tag wikis don't, or if one does I'd link it instead.  Also, being shown the existence of one tag wiki should clue in most people that it's a thing, and they can probably see how to navigate to the wikis for other tags with some clicking.  (The tag mouseover popups used to include tag-wiki links; now they don't so it takes more clicks, but still.)

Comment: @Peter, yeah well, I tried to write the Tag Wiki for my small Tag as short as possible (I only put 3 Resources Links in it), and it's a "first" Version, I may improve it over time... :wink: // And yep indeed about "Also, being shown the existence of one tag wiki should clue in most people that it's a thing, and they can probably see how to navigate to the wikis for other tags with some clicking.", but that works for "you and me" as "Answerers", I wouldn't take that Reasoning "for granted" for 1-Rep Users (in "my" Tag at least) who just want some quick Solution...

Comment: @chivracq: If people choose not to help themselves when shown information, there's not much it's worth trying to do.

Comment: Got some Auto-Notif about "avoid extended discussions in comments.", and I think we both agree..., + moving a bit away from @OP's Intention/Qt..., even if hum, I found "I tried to edit a tag wiki to get my Tag Editor badge" quite funny when I read the Qt, ah-ah...! [Spoiler: You also get +2 Pts if your Tag (Wiki) Edit gets approved, youpiddoo...!] Editing a Tag (Wiki) is meant for "Quality", not to get a Badge, I would think...!

Comment: Gotta get all the badges lol

Comment: OK, you got me a good Laugh, nearly crying, ah-ah...!